# What is the optimal select according to you?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

What is the optimal select according to you?

```
select @MailTo=ISNULL((select data from filedata where descid=3104 and DataId=evt04) ,'') 
from event_21  
where evtid=@nFileId
```

or

```
select @MailTo=ISNULL(data ,'') 
from event_21  
innerjoin filedata  on event_21.evt04=filedata.dataid
where descid=3104   
and evtid=@nFileId
```

Comment: Do `EXPLAIN` on both and see if there's a difference; there likely isn't.

Comment: `EXPLAIN` is not a Sql Server 2008 feature. Use `SHOWPLAN` and `STATISTICS` instead.

Comment: From a style perspective, I always prefer joins. From a performance perspective, I've almost always seen joins perform faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously "join" is faster than "inline select query". I have tested with 1000 rows. You can also test. here is the sample test code.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tableA](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tableA] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tableB](
    [RowId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Designation] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tableB] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [RowId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

Declare  @Min       Int = 1
        ,@Max       Int = 1000

While (@Min <= @Max)
Begin
    Insert Into tableA(Name)
    Select  'Name would be the name of - ' + Cast(@Min As Nvarchar(10))

    Insert Into tableB(Id,Designation)
    Select   @Min
            ,'Desig could be the name of - Name' + Cast(@Min As Nvarchar(10))

    Select  @Min = @Min + 1
End
```

First look @ inline select query

```
-- inline query
Select   a.Id
        ,a.Name
        ,(Select Designation From tableB As b Where b.Id = a.Id) As Designation
From    tableA As a With (Nolock)
```

**output:**

[image]

**Execution Plan:**

[image]

now the Join query :-

```
---- join 
Select   a.Id
        ,a.Name
        ,b.Designation
From    tableA As a With (Nolock)
        Join tableB As b On a.Id = b.Id
```

**execution plan for join query :-**
[image]
you can see the clear difference.